# Change app language using button programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm developing an iOS app with five languages.I have done all the coding and now I'm trying to switch between languages using the button.But can't change the language..I found the problem but cant find the solution.

```
    [NSBundle setLanguage:code];
```

Problem this line not calling..
Any help please? thanks..

Comment: You can change the "AppleLanguages" userdefualts and set whatever language you want, but app needs a restart to work.

Comment: but I want it without app restart..

Comment: Unfortunately that is the only way if you are depending on Apple localization.

Comment: if you want to use it without app-restart you have to build the localization yourself. You can still use .strings-Files but need to use a function to pull the right translation for the current setting instead of just the translation for a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `localization` to change the language of the application without restart.

1. Go to project -> select your project in the document outline -> Add the new language.

[image]

2. Add `Localized.strings` files to your project.

[image]

3. Add the strings which are used for localization in `Localizable.strings(XXX)`

For English `"hello" = "Hello World";`

For Hindi `"hello" = "नमस्ते दुनिया";`

**Code:**

```
import UIKit

extension String {

    var localized: String {
        let lang = currentLanguage()
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
    }

    //Remove here and add these in utilities class
    func saveLanguage(_ lang: String) {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(lang, forKey: "Locale")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

    func currentLanguage() -> String {

        return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Locale") ?? ""
    }
}

enum Language: String {
    case english = "English"
    case hindi = "हिंदी"
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var language = Language.english

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Initial Setup
        String().saveLanguage("en")
        languageLabel.text = "hello".localized
        languageButton.setTitle(language.rawValue, for: .normal)
    }

    func updateLanguage() {

        if language == .english {
            String().saveLanguage("hi")
            language = .hindi
        } else {
            String().saveLanguage("en")
            language = .english
        }

        languageLabel.text = "hello".localized
        languageButton.setTitle(language.rawValue, for: .normal)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var languageLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var languageButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func changeLanguageButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        updateLanguage()
    }
}
```

[image]